# How do we know that the peak of human eye sensitivity is at 555 nm?

Tags: optics, visible-light, electromagnetic-radiation, vision, biology

How do we know that the human eye is most sensitive to a light of wavelength of $555$ $nm$ and  power of $1/683$ watt? How are experiments performed for obtaining this result? What's so special about the number $683$?

Comment: Well, you do experiments to see (so to speak). And yes, I can come up with a variety of ways of measuring the response, so experiments are certainly conceivable.

Comment: Wouldn't you just try different wavelengths at different power levels and see which one can be detected at the lowest power level?

Comment: So u mean 1/683 watt is the lowest power at which the eye responds to the 555 nm light.

Comment: @shahrozeshahab - no, nobody denies eye would respond to less than 1/683 W of visible light. Actually, eye can easily detect some picowatts of light in the cyan-green color range.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spectral sensitivity a human eye can be measured in an experiment. One of the methods of behavioral* measurement of spectral eye sensitivity, named [flicker photometry](http://www.yorku.ca/eye/flicker.htm), works as quoted below.

> **Minimum Flicker**
>
> The perceptual criterion in heterochromatic flicker photometry is a just noticeable flicker. If the two fields alternate slowly, e.g., around 2 Hz (cycles per second) the observer will first see one color and then the other. As the frequency of alternation increases the colors will begin to fuse. For example, if a red and white field are being alternated they will fuse to a pulsating pink. If the frequency gets very high, e.g., around 35-40 Hz then the pulsating flicker will disappear unless the radiance differences between the test and reference fields is very large. However, when the frequency of alternation between the test and reference fields is about 15-20 Hz the perception of flicker will disappear for a very narrow range of chromatic field radiance. The observer is asked to adjust the amount of chromatic light until a threshold amount of flicker is perceived.

Now to the "magic" number 683. It's just an artefact of the definition of [candela](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Candela), which is the unit chosen to be close to the older unit, *standard candle*, divided by 60. See more details on history in corresponding [Wikipedia section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Candela#History).

Note that candela (and thus the number 683) is not related to the threshold of sensitivity of vision$^\dagger$, nor to optimal luminance for any kind of visual task. Its significance is no more than that of meter: simply an arbitrary human-scale unit.

---

<sub>* Apart from behavioral measurements, one can use electroretinograms that determine spectral sensitivity of whole eyes, as well as microspectrophotometry, i.e. measurement of absorptivity of individual retinal pigments.

$^\dagger$ Rod cell sensitivity threshold order of magnitude is $10^{-6}\,\mathrm{cd}/\mathrm{m}^2$. Cone cell threshold is about $5\times 10^{-3}\,\mathrm{cd}/\mathrm{m}^2$.</sub>